# Tensor product of $K$-skew fields is nilpotent iff every $D_{i}$ is nilpotent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples, tensor-products, noncommutative-algebra

an element, x, of a ring, R, is called nilpotent if there exists some positive integer, n, such that $x^n = 0$.

in book Skew Fields by P.K. DRAXL :
Definition 3 . A simple ring $A$ with finite $|A:Z(A)|$ is called a
"central simple $K-algebra$" ($ K := Z(A)$ ). If a central simple $ K$-algebra
is a skew field then we call it a "$K$-skew field".

now is following statement true ?

let every  $D_{i}$ is $K$-skew field then  $ \otimes _{i=1}^{n}   D_{i}$ is nilpotent iff every  $D_{i}$ is nilpotent .($ \otimes $ : is tensor product over $K$. we say that $D_{i}$ is nilpotent if $D_{i}$ has maximal subfield $F$ and $F/Z(D_i)$ Galois extension and Galois group $Gal(F/Z(D_i))$ be  nilpotent group)

I think it is not true but i can't find counterexample.

Comment: What does it mean for $D_i$ to be nilpotent?

Comment: @EricWofsey. I edit my question.